# Largest set of natural numbers such that when picking any three, one divides the sum of the other two?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

> What's the largest set of natural numbers such that:
>
> - no number divides any other
> - pick any three numbers, one of those three divides the sum of the other two

Found this problem on [puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60759/a-special-number-set) (*[source](http://www.diophante.fr/problemes-ouverts/84-problemes-ouverts/3900-e133-beaucoup-d-appeles-mais-peu-d-elus)*) and decided to ask here after playing with it a bit.

**Edit:** I was able to find examples for sets of sizes $\le6$ with a brute force search, such as:

$\{2, 3, 5, 7, 107, 10693\},\{2, 3, 5, 7, 193, 3467\},\{2, 3, 5, 7, 317, 31693\},\dots$ 
$\{2, 3, 5, 13, 107, 10267\},\{2, 3, 5, 13, 127, 17267\},\{2, 3, 5, 13, 497, 47707\},\dots$ 
$\{2, 3, 5, 17, 73, 13867\},$ $\{2, 3, 5, 17, 97, 14353\},\{2, 3, 5, 17, 607, 89833\},\dots$ 
$\{2, 3, 7, 11, 235, 26309\}, \{2, 3, 7, 11, 437, 60295\}, \{2, 3, 7, 11, 697, 78053\}, \dots$

But I was not able to extend any of these so far to seven elements.

**Update:** Looks like [this thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c33h1435897_2017_iran_tst2_p2) linked in the comments by [Arnaud Mortier](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/480423/arnaud-mortier) contains a proof.

Comment: Could you add another number to the list on the right, say? I suspect some computer code would be useful here. Is that how you found these sets?

Comment: @stuartstevenson You can try. I've searched up to $10^7$  for these two size six sets with no luck.

Comment: Any conjectures on the matter?

Comment: Here is a proof that $n=6$ (at the bottom): https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c33h1435897_2017_iran_tst2_p2

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I think you should post it as an self contained answer.

Comment: I didn't want initially because "link-only" answers get erased by moderators. So I reproduced the statements of the lemmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [proof that n=6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c33h1435897_2017_iran_tst2_p2).

I'll just reproduce the statements of the successive lemmas used in the proof.

Let $S$ be a set satisfying the conditions of the problem.

- Lemma 1: There are at most two even numbers in $S$.
- Lemma 2: If $x_i>x_j,x_k$ all lie in $S$, then $x_i|x_j+x_k$ if and only if $x_i=x_j+x_k$.
- Lemma 3: If there are two even numbers in $S$, the larger even number is the maximal element in $S$.
- Lemma 4: If there exists a working set with $n$ elements, there exists a working set with $n$ elements that contains $2$.
- Lemma 5: $\sharp S=7$ implies that $S$ cannot contain $2$.